# How to Handle Validation Error Message on Before Insert for the Same Field?

Tags: apex, trigger, before-trigger, salesforce-for-outlook

I had a requirement earlier inwhich whenever I insert a task it always stamp current user's Business unit to Task Business Unit.
below were the code that I had written on before insert trigger.

```
User u = [Select Id, Name, BU__c,Multiple_BU_User__c from User where Id = : UserInfo.getUserId()];
if (tasksForProcessing <> null) {
    for (Task t: tasksForProcessing) {
        if (String.isBlank(t.BU__c)) {
            t.BU__c = u.BU__c;
        }

    }
}
```

Now our client has introduced an additional field called as Multiple BU.The purpose of this field is user may belongs to multiple BU(Earlier every users belongs to single BU).This field is of type checkbox.So when a user belongs to Multiple BU then this field checkbox is set to true.
Now they want to put validation rule on task like when **Multiple_BU_User__c=true and BU__c=blank** then they want to throw the validation message here.
Problem is as per salesforce order of execution,All Before Triggers execute first then validation rule.
So when user belongs to multiple BU,it does not throw validation message for such users because I am assigning Business Unit Value on before insert event.

So I have tried to divide this code into 2 parts.
Below code is for Single Business Unit User which is working as expected:

```
User u = [Select Id, Name, BU__c,Multiple_BU_User__c from User where Id = : UserInfo.getUserId() AND Multiple_BU_User__c=false];
if (tasksForProcessing <> null) {
    for (Task t: tasksForProcessing) {
        if (String.isBlank(t.BU__c)) {
            t.BU__c = u.BU__c;
        }

    }
}
```

Below code is for Multiple Business Unit User which is not working as expected:

```
User usr = [Select Id, Name,BU__C,Multiple_BU_User__c from User where Id = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND Multiple_Business_Unit_User__c=true]; 
if (tasksForProcessing <> null) {
    for (Task tsk: tasksForProcessing) {

        if(String.isBlank(tsk.BU))
        {
            tsk.addError(Label.Task_Validation_Error);       
        }
        else if(String.valueOf(tsk.Subject).contains(':')) {
            system.debug('Contains :');
            tsk.BU__c = usr.BU__c;
        }
    }
```

In this code I want to display validation message while creating task if user sets Business Unit value as blank that I have mentioned in IF block.

Problem comes when I am trying to create a task via Salesforce For Outlook(When we add any email to salesforce it stores in contact as a task),it does not allow me to create a task as it throws validation message.

> As per salesforce order of execution this is valid because Before
>   Trigger executes first then Validation Message.

In this case I am setting the Business Unit Value and at the same time I am checking validation message which creates a conflict in this case.

> Instead of  if(String.isBlank(tsk.BusinessUnit__c)) this perticular
>   condition if I use another condition like 
>   if(String.valueOf(tsk.Subject).startsWith('Email:'))  for SFO it will
>   cause the problem when user is from differnt country(Local Value is
>   other than English)

I want to know what is the best option that I can try in such situation?

Answer (score 3):

This will do what you want

Adjust your list:

```
User u = [Select Id, Name, BU__c,Multiple_BU_User__c from User where Id = : UserInfo.getUserId() AND Multiple_BU_User__c=false];

task[] tasksForProcessing = New Task[]{};
//...add items to list...

    for (Task t: tasksForProcessing) {
        if(t.Multiple_BU_User__c == true && string.isBlank(t.BU__c)){
                t.addError('You must enter a business unit');
        }else if (String.isBlank(t.BU__c)) {
            t.BU__c = u.BU__c;
        }

    }
```

Now if that causes issues with other use cases you will need to reconcile that with the needs of the business. If they are important enough then find a way to make it working within the other requirements. They can't expect to put you in a unending loop and expect you to get out.

If you are allowed to use the User BU in presence of Multiple_BU_User__c then you could do this:

```
User u = [Select Id, Name, BU__c,Multiple_BU_User__c from User where Id = : UserInfo.getUserId() AND Multiple_BU_User__c=false];

task[] tasksForProcessing = New Task[]{};
//...add items to list...

    for (Task t: tasksForProcessing) {
        if (String.isBlank(t.BU__c)) {
            t.BU__c = u.BU__c;
        }

        if(t.Multiple_BU_User__c == true && string.isBlank(t.BU__c)){
                t.addError('You must enter a business unit');

        }
    }
```

Which would set the BU based not he User BU and after that if still blank and multiple_BU is true it will throw validation error

**Note** The above will fall flat on its face if loading tasks from a data loader. You will need to map the user Id to User records and get them within the loop using the Task Owner Id

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54579/discussion-on-answer-by-eric-how-to-handle-validation-error-message-on-before-in).